# Symfony Forms EntityType Select All using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

On my webpage, I am using a Symfony Form with an EntityType class. I want to create an extra button that selects all items from this dropdown on click. Is this possible using JavaScript / JQuery? Simply changing the automatic generated HTML does not work.

FormType.php:

```
->add('item', EntityType::class, [
   'class' => Item::class,
   'choice_label' => function(Item $item) {
      return sprintf('%s', $item->getName());
    },
    'label' => 'Staff',
    'multiple' => true,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like that would do the trick :

```html
<!-- Somewhere in your Twig file : -->
<button id="check-all-options">Check all !</button>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#check-all-options').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Select all the options of your <select> tag
  const options = document.querySelectorAll('#form_item option');

  // Loop on all the options and pass them to selected ✅
  options.forEach(option => option.selected = true);
});
```

Let me know if it helps :)